# .net core 3 api Не получается принять пустой объект в get

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0-webapi

Есть экшен (упрощен для теста):

```
   [HttpGet]
   public IActionResult Get(FilterDevice filter)
   {
       var res = _deviceService.FindByFilter(filter);
       return Ok(res);
   }
```

Я тестирую через `Postman`. Если я в `body` передаю пустоту, то вижу:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|82c124df-49b871e3057be666.",
    "errors": {
        "$": [
            "The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."
        ]
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если я передаю пустой объект: в `body` пишу `{}`, то все ОК:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы я при пустоте получал то же самое, что я получаю при `{}` и почему вообще такое происходит (В MVC 5 такогго не было).

Comment: может проще сделать 2 метода GET? один с параметрои, второй без

Comment: @tym32167 попробую..но это дубляж получается

Comment: @tym32167 с таким же роутом не получается...пишет что на один роут несколько экшенов

Comment: а зачем вообще принимать такие параметры в гет запросе? Нельзя по старинке, `myurl?param1=1&param2=2...`  с простыми типами данных типа строка, число и тд?

Comment: @tym32167 у меня прога вся общается через `json` (angular + .net mvc 5)...решили перевести на кору...что мне, теперь ангуляр править?, чтобы он не json отправлял, а тчо то другое ?

Comment: да отправляйте что хотите, я только указал на необычность идеи отправки json в теле get запроса

Comment: @tym32167 дак с постом та же история

Comment: вы отправляете запрос с `Content-Type: application/json`, обработчик соответственно ждет `json`

Comment: @tCode почему так происходит, я понял. Факт в том что на `mvc 5` все работало. Видимо биндер мог это обработать. Как сделать чтобы в коре биндер мог это(пустоту) тоже обработать. Либо что нужно переписать ) я этой инфы не нашел

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, а что мешает передавать параметры в урле запроса?

Comment: @tCode 1) параметр может быть пустым. 2) Не красиво как то получается

Answer (score 1):

Перед `FilterDevice` поставить `[FromQuery]`?

Answer (score 0):

Это может быть связанно использованием middleware, попробуй сбросить позицию каретки в потоке, это можно сделать через регистрацию дополнительной мидлвари, она должна быть зарегистрирована последней.

```
internal class TestMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public TestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        if (next != null)
            await next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Доп ссылки:

- https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5251458/net-core-3-0-logging-middleware-by-pipereader
- https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/41304

Comment: я в документации находил, что такое поведение свойствено, но поробую вашу рекомендацию...в данный момент решил тем, что просто в `Middleware` сбросил валидацию. Спасибо за ваш ответ, обязательно поробую )

Answer (score 0):

Как вам такой вариант? С чтением `Request.Body` и проверкой контента на `null`

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    DeviceFilter filter = new DeviceFilter();
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
    {
        var content = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
        {
            return Ok(filter);
        }
    }

    filter = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeviceFilter>(content);
    var res = _deviceService.FindByFilter(filter);

    return Ok(res);
}
```

Comment: если прописать `ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions` => `options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;`, то в принципе  тоже самое, но тогда можно написать: `[HttpGet()] public IActionResult Get(FilterDevice filter)`